# Google chrome error after installing Ethereum Wallet and vice versa

Tags: wallets, linux

Anybody here knows why Google Chrome runs into error opening up after Ethereum wallet is installed?

And when I reinstall Google Chrome, the Ethereum Wallet is gone. What the hell?

I am using Linux Mint.

Comment: Same sh!t here, Linux Mint 18.1 (Serena). Unbelievable.